# php - using a hyper link to send variable used in data base to use get command to echoe results

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table with arrays pulling information from a database, I have linked the fix to be a hyperlink "click me for fix" I have entered the link to send the variable to a php that will use $GET to echoe the information.

code below , i am new to php and been racking brains . the only out put i get is Welcome . (done welcome to test if information was being passed)

```
<div id=list>

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect('172.16.254.111',"user","password","Faults"); //(connection location , username to sql, password to sql, name of db)
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//where statement in the sql syntax will select where in db to get infor, use AND to add another condition
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Fixes WHERE Product='Serv1U' AND Fault_type='Broadcast Manager'"); //this creates a variable that selects the database

//below is the echo statment to create the results in a table format, list collumn titles
echo "<table id=tables border='1'> 
<tr>
<th>Products</th>
<th>Fault_type</th>
<th>Fault_Description</th>
<th>Fix</th>
</tr>";

//below is script to list reults in a table format, $row [row name on table] 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Product'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Fault_type'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Fault_Description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href=\"idfix.php?Fix=" . $rows['Fix'] . "\">Click for Fix</a></td>"; //this is how you link into an echo, alsothe id=" hopefully means i can send ID information.
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

// below closes the coonection to mysql
mysqli_close($con);
```

**index.php:**

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["Fix"]; ?>.
```

I'm lost. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
                                            ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just a typo here? `$GET` must be `$_GET`.

And it should be `$row['Fix']` not `$rows['Fix']`! Note the 's'!

Comment: i will test , cant believe it is just a typo been pulling my hair out over this lol